# When posting a form using FormMixin in Detail View in django, it does not post data

Tags: django

I am trying to write comments on a post and which is in DetailView using FormMixin. When iI try to post the comment, it does not post it but just gives the CSRF data in the url bar.

here is my View

```
class PostDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    form_class = CommentCreationForm

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk' : self.object.id})

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    print("********************")
    print("Context taken")
    print("********************")
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = CommentCreationForm(initial={
        'post': self.object
    })
    return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print("********************")
    print("Post taken")
    print("********************")
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)

def form_valid(self, form):
    print("********************")
    print("Valid taken")
    print("********************")
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    form.save()
    return super(PostDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

this is what i get in url bar

> http://localhost:8000/blog/post/29/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=MFUjN61oQRLHOoBDKwfpc5vuklTW3nnhmtRXFlflOGeFyhEim1H8OBMsEnmZ6YaT&content=asdafdsf

CommentCreationForm

```
class CommentCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'author',
            'post',
            'content',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'content':  forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textarea', 'rows': '5'})
        }
```

Comment: somehow it is sending GET request instead of POST.`form method="post"`

Comment: okay, but why? and how can i resolve it?

Comment: can you post CommentCreation form ? Are you using any html form ?

Comment: there you go.. and no, im just using this form to post data into my Post model

Comment: I solved it on my own. all i needed to do was to specify method="post"

Comment: where you put `method="post"`